# Error binding parameter '3' using wtforms, mysqlalchemy with Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

New to Flask, and this is my first post here! Working on a form entry with a SelectMultipleField entry that is returning a 'binding parameter '3' error.

In forms.py:

```
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()

class SWProductForm(FlaskForm):
    string_of_files = [
    'genomics', 'mapping', 'identification', 'analytics', 'statistics', 'NDVI', 'imagery', 'testing', 'marketing', 'supplychain', 'irrigation'
    ]
    files = [(x, x) for x in string_of_files]

sw_categories = MultiCheckboxField(
        'Category', 
        choices=files,
        validators=[DataRequired()] 
    )
```

in models.py:

```
class SWProducts(db.Model):
    sw_categories = db.Column(
        db.String,
        index=False,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False
    )

   def __init__(self, sw_categories):
        self.sw_categories = sw_categories
```

in routes.py:

```
@home_bp.route('/ag-software-entry', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ag_software_entry():
    form = SWProductForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_submitted():
            print ("submitted")
        if form.validate():
            print ("valid")
        print(form.errors)
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            # Get Form Fields
            sw_categories = form.sw_categories.data

            sw_products = SWProducts(
                sw_categories = form.sw_categories.data,             
                )

            db.session.add(sw_products)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Record was successfully added')

            return render_template(
                'software_entry.html',
                sw_products=sw_products
                )
        else:
            print("bad")
    return render_template('add_new_agtech_sw.html', form=form)
```

html/jinja:

```
  <fieldset class="form-field">
      {{ form.sw_categories.label }}
      <br />
      {{ form.sw_categories }}
      {% if form.sw_categories.errors %}
      <ul class="errors">
        {% for error in form.sw_categories.errors %}
          <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      {% endif %}
    </fieldset>
```

The full error is: sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO sw_products (sw_company_name, sw_company_product, sw_software_components, sw_categories, sw_product_description, sw_product_img, sw_os_license, sw_references, sw_locations_desc, sw_locations_img) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Software Company', 'Software Product', 'Software ELement', ['mapping', 'statistics', 'NDVI'], 'Product Desc', 'Screen_Shot_2021-03-20_at_11.35.51_AM.png', 'OS License', 'SW References', 'SW Locations', 'Screen_Shot_2021-03-20_at_11.35.51_AM.png')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)

I took out other field entries as it was working before adding the checkbox options.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found the solution. It is a matter of using the join method in routes:

```
   sw_categories = ', '.join(form.sw_categories.data)
```